# how to split one string column of `(12345)some_string` to two column `12345`, `some_string` in Oracle

Tags: oracle

As the question,

how to split one string column of `(12345)some_string` to two-column `12345`and `some_string` in Oracle?

Notice: Not all the columns are `(12345)some_string`, part of columns are only `some_string` without `(12345)`, the two columns are `null` and `some string`

Comment: Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it. SO is not a codewriting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sample data you posted, this could be one option (line #5 onward):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '(12345)some_string' from dual union all
  3     select 'another_string'     from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_substr(col, '\d+') col1,
  6         substr(col, instr(col, ')') + 1) col2
  7  from test;

COL1               COL2
------------------ ------------------
12345              some_string
                   another_string

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, what if `(Ab56.12345)some_string` not `(12345)some_string`?

Comment: I created a new question, thanks so so much for your answer,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703139/how-to-split-one-string-column-of-ab-12345some-string-to-two-column-ab-1234

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following table:

```sql
create table my_table (my_column varchar2(30));
insert into my_table values ('(12345)some_string');
commit;
```

**1) Add a new column to the table**

```sql
alter table my_table add new_column number;`
```

**2) Fill the new column**

```sql
update my_table set new_column = regexp_substr(my_column, '^\(([1-9]+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1);
```

**3) Update the original column**

```sql
update my_table set my_column = regexp_replace(my_column, '^\([1-9]+\)', '');
```