# how to split one string column of `(Ab56.12345)some_string` to two column `Ab.12345`, `some_string` in Oracle

Tags: oracle

As the question,

how to split one string column of `(Ab56.12345)some_string` to two-column `Ab56.12345`and `some_string` in Oracle?

Notice: Not all the columns are `(Ab56.12345)some_string`, part of columns are only `some_string` without `(Ab56.12345)`, the two columns are `null` and `some string`

This answer from @Littlefoot can't solve my question now

````
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '(12345)some_string' from dual union all
  3     select 'another_string'     from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_substr(col, '\d+') col1,
  6         substr(col, instr(col, ')') + 1) col2
  7  from test;
```

COL1               COL2
------------------ ------------------
12345              some_string
                   another_string
````

Comment: @astentx Hi, yes, how to join the original table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group here:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '\((.+?)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS COL1,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '\(.+?\)', '') AS COL2
FROM test;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for saving my day!!!!!!! Can you recommend some books or tutorials about this?

Comment: @FIREUSD Honestly Stack Overflow is one of the best places to learn about SQL.  Just about every possible question has already been asked and answered here.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Or, without regular expressions, using `substr` + `instr` combination:

```
SQL> WITH test(col) AS (
  2      SELECT '(12345)some_string' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3      SELECT 'another_string'     FROM dual UNION ALL
  4      SELECT '(Ab56.12345)string' FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT
  7    replace(replace(substr(col, 1, instr(col, ')')), '(', ''), ')', '') col1,
  8    substr(col, instr(col, ')') + 1) col2
  9  FROM test;

COL1               COL2
------------------ ------------------
12345              some_string
                   another_string
Ab56.12345         string

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your this answer, I will remember your answer, but I already accepted another answer,I am sorry

Comment: Or do you know how to join the result to original table?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703450/how-to-split-one-string-column-of-ab56-12345some-string-to-two-column-ab-12